# Condition for a graph to be Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory

I am proving 
A graph G with number of vertices v (>2) has Hamiltonian cycle provided the number of vertices of degree k does not exceed k , for each k , where k lies between 1 and (v-1)/2 . 
I tried to proof by contradiction but I am not getting contradict .

Comment: I'm not positive, but I suspect a possible angle would be proving that the closure of the graph is complete, which would infer that the original graph is Hamiltonian.